# R expression for cdot

Tags: r

I know R's `expression` function can rendor LaTeX' `cdot` with `%.%`:

```r
expression(x %.% y)
```

However, I'm trying to write the probability, P(·). And this gives me an error in R:

```r
expression(P( %.% ))
```

```
unexpected token '%.%'
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`expression` expects syntactically valid R code. A binary operator requires operands.

But luckily these operands don’t have to be visible, and plotmath renders `NULL` as invisible; an alternative way of writing this is to use `{}` instead of `NULL`:

```
expression(P({} %.% {}))
```